# Calculating price based on changing hourly rates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Imagine I have a business that rents widgets by the minute, but the rental rates vary depending on the day of the week and hour of the day.  I describe this information in a "Rates" table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Rates (
    DayNumber int,
    HourNumber int,
    HourlyRate decimal(19,4),
    PRIMARY KEY (DayNumber, HourNumber)
)

DayNumber  HourNumber  HourlyRate
---------  ----------  ----------
1          1           3.75
1          2           4.50
1          3           4.25
1          4           3.75
```

In the above table, the day number is retrieved from `datepart(dw, Start)`, the hour number from `datepart(hour, Start)`.  It has 168 records (the number of hours in a standard week).

I have the rental information as follows in a "Rentals" table:

```
CREATE TABLE Rentals (
    RentalId int,
    CustomerId int,
    Start datetimeoffset,
    Finish datetimeoffset,
    Cost decimal(19,4),
    PRIMARY KEY (RentalId)
)

RentalId  CustomerId  Start            Finish           Cost
--------  ----------  ---------------  ---------------  ----
1         1           1/1/2016 6:11am  1/1/2016 2:34pm  
2         1           1/2/2016 7:23am  1/3/2016 8:12am
```

Using T-SQL (SQL Server 2014 or better), I'd like to update the Rentals table to calculate the `Cost` column that considers the rate of each day-hour, summed up for the total rental period.  Bonus points for efficiency.

Comment: Does the `HourNumber` applies for 24HH format? Say the rate of `HourNumber 4` applies for 4 a.m., 4 p.m. or both?

Comment: To calculate the cost, do you want to use the starting rate for the whole duration of the rental or use the rate that apply for all specific hours of the rentals's duration?

Comment: @JoshPart `datepart(hour, Start)` would return `4` for 4 am and `16` for 4 pm.

Comment: @AXMIM the rates that apply for specific hours. So if something starts at 1:30 pm and ends at 4:45 pm, and the rate is $1 for 1:00 pm, $2 for 2:00 pm, $3 for 3:00 pm, and $4 for 4:00 pm, then that's $.50 + $2 + $3 + $3 = $8.50.

Comment: I think what you want/need is quite complicated to do in pure SQL, so I suggest you better do it on your client side. I'm not saying you CAN'T do this on SQL, but maybe it would be less complicated and less time-consumig to do in your client program.

Comment: @JoshPart True, however there is some awkwardness in implementing it client-side due to other architectural considerations (e.g. race conditions).  Writing this in C# is plan B.

Comment: Write a function that takes day, hour, and #minutes and returns cost.  Then you'll have to loop through all partial hours and hours for the span and sum.  It's possible, but not pretty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested in SSMS, it updates the table now. It solved the issues below:

1) it works no matter whether or not START and FINISH are on the same day;

2) it works no matter whether or not START and FINISH are on the same week or month.

```
update rentals
set cost = (select sum(hourlyrate) from rates 
                where (daynumber > datepart(dw,start) and daynumber < datepart(dw,finish)) or
                (daynumber = datepart(dw,start) and hournumber >  datepart(hour,start)) or
                (daynumber = datepart(dw,finish) and hournumber <  datepart(hour,finish))
                ) + 
                (select hourlyrate from rates
                where daynumber = datepart(dw,start) and hournumber =  datepart(hour,start)
                ) * 1.00 * (60-datepart(minute, start))/60 +
                (select hourlyrate from rates
                where daynumber = datepart(dw,finish) and hournumber =  datepart(hour,finish)
                ) * 1.00 * datepart(minute, finish)/60 -
                (
                    Case when datediff(day,start,finish)%7 = 0 then 230 -- deal with same day case
                         when datediff(day,start,finish)%7 <> 0 then 0
                    end
                ) +
                (select datediff(day,start,finish)/7 * sum(hourlyrate) from rates) -- deal with multiple weeks case
```

Comment: Good solution, you need to fix your condition however because it doesn't calculate the right cost. Also, you could simplify to have only one aggregate. I suspect doing so would also fix the cost calculation as well.

Comment: @AXMIM, thanks for pointing out, i update my answer, and now it works and even for several corner cases as well.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was able to use your previous (though less correct) answer as inspiration for how to solve this problem, and do it efficiently.  Cheers!

Comment: @GeoffArmstrong, the thing is if some one may rent the gadget for more than 1 week, this updated version is better.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [tally table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/) to split record into one record per hour.

For example, the following rental

```
RentalId  CustomerId  Start            Finish           Cost
--------  ----------  ---------------  ---------------  ----
1         1           1/1/2016 1:30pm  1/1/2016 4:45pm
```

is processed using tally into

```
RentalId  Start            Finish           Cost
--------  ---------------  ---------------  ----
1         1/1/2016 1:30pm  1/1/2016 2:00pm  1
1         1/1/2016 2:00pm  1/1/2016 3:00pm  2
1         1/1/2016 3:00pm  1/1/2016 4:00pm  3
1         1/1/2016 4:00pm  1/1/2016 4:45pm  4
```

With this, you can calculate the cost of each preprocessed records. You have to use rate per minute since not all records lasted a full hour.

Then, just sum these costs grouped by rental and you have got the cost of each rentals.

Here is the complete solution.
I used [CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) for the tally table and preprocessed records.

```
;WITH
N0(_)            AS (SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT NULL),
N1(_)            AS (SELECT NULL FROM N0 AS L CROSS JOIN N0 AS R),
N2(_)            AS (SELECT NULL FROM N1 AS L CROSS JOIN N1 AS R),
N3(_)            AS (SELECT NULL FROM N2 AS L CROSS JOIN N2 AS R),
Tally            AS (SELECT N = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))  FROM N3 AS L CROSS JOIN N3 AS R),

PreprocessedData AS (SELECT Rent.RentalId,
                            BillingStart =( CASE WHEN Tally.N = 1 THEN                          
                                                Rent.Start
                                            ELSE
                                                DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, DATEADD(HOUR, Tally.N - 1, Rent.Start)), 0)--Trim exceeding minutes
                                            END),
                            BillingEnd = (  CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, Rent.Start, Rent.Finish) < Tally.N THEN    
                                                Rent.Finish
                                            ELSE
                                                DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, DATEADD(HOUR, Tally.N, Rent.Start)), 0)--Trim exceeding minutes
                                            END),
                            Rate.HourlyRate
                    FROM Rentals AS Rent
                    INNER JOIN Tally ON DATEDIFF(HOUR, Rent.Start, Rent.Finish) >= Tally.N - 1  -- DATEADD(HOUR, Tally.N, Rent.Start) < Rent.Finish
                    LEFT JOIN Rates AS Rate ON  DATEPART(DW, DATEADD(HOUR, Tally.N - 1, Rent.Start)) = Rate.DayNumber
                                                AND DATEPART(HOUR, DATEADD(HOUR, Tally.N - 1, Rent.Start)) = Rate.HourNumber
                    )



UPDATE Rentals
SET Cost = CalculateCostPerRental.CalculateCost 
FROM Rentals
INNER JOIN (SELECT  RentalId,
                    CalculateCost = SUM(HourlyRate * DATEDIFF(MINUTE, BillingStart, BillingEnd) /60)
            FROM PreprocessedData
            GROUP BY RentalId
            HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN HourlyRate IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 0 /*Update only if all the rates where found*/) AS CalculateCostPerRental ON Rentals.RentalId = CalculateCostPerRental.RentalId
/*cost is null when there is a rate missing in rate table*/
```

As for performance, they are poor, but it is due to your database design. <s>Without, changing the design, it's going to be really hard to do better than what this solution does.</s> However, I would challenge if if you really need rocking performance for this task.

Disclaimer : You should do some testing before using this in production because I haven't tested every edge case there is. Also, you might have missing rates in your rate table.

Comment: What changes would you recommend in the table structure to improve performance?

Comment: Before recommending changes, it would be best to know in which context this will be run. For instance, how often and for how many rentals will be calculated each time. If this is a one shot deal, I wouldn't bother with performance. I wouldn't either if this is run with only a few hundred of rentals per day. However, I take back by world about my solution being hard to beat. Although, it's not working properly right now, Dance-Henry's solution have to potential to beat mine. Especially on really long rental.

Comment: @GeoffArmstrong My previous handling of missing rates in rate table was really wrong. It was computing a price anyway which is really bad. Please see my edit, I have updated the missing rate handling.